# Take two numbers, and countinue only, if it's not lower or equal to zero

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner programmer, and I need some help with my code.I need it, to only let the user countinue, when they give a number that's not lower, or equal to zero. If they write 0 or less, it should ask for input again. I tried some while methods, but doesn't seem to get the hang of it. Here is my code so far. I appreciate if you could help me solve this!

```
namespace Exercism
{
    class Practice
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Írd be az első számot!");
            double x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                if (x <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A szám nem lehet kisebb, vagy egyenlő mint 0!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Írd be újra a számot!");
                
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Helyes érték, tovább mehetsz!");
                }
            
                Console.WriteLine("Írd be a második számot!");
                double y = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (y <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A szám nem lehet kisebb, vagy egyenlő mint 0!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Várj egy kicsit, számolok...");
                }
            
            double sum = x + y;
            double dif = x - y;
            double sub = x / y;
            sub = Math.Round(sub,2);
            double multi = x * y;

            Console.WriteLine("A két szám összege: " + sum);
            Console.WriteLine("A két szám különbsége: " + dif);
            Console.WriteLine("A két szám osztása: " + sub);
            Console.WriteLine("A két szám szorzata: " + multi);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double x) || x <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number.");`

Comment: Please either remove or translate the Writelines, because these are not going to be understood by a vast majority and make up almost half of the entire snippet.

Comment: _"I tried some while methods, but doesn't seem to get the hang of it."_ **Post your attempts**. How can we know what you're struggling with if we don't see what you attempted to do to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a solution like this:

```
Int32 x = 0;

  while (x < 1)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter number greater then zero: ");
     x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if (x < 1)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Error - must be a positive number. \n");
     }

  }

  Console.WriteLine("Nice. You made it.");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This will display the error message even if you enter a positive number. It also doesn't take into account invalid inputs. Consider using `TryParse` instead. Lastly, the OP is dealing with doubles, not ints.

Comment: now its fix. You are right about using TryParse - if you cannot control the input from the use.

Answer (score 0):

:)

Thank you all for the answers! Palestine, I did not find the answer I was looking for, or at least I did not understand it BUT, thanks to that question, I've found a youtube video, that helped me figure it out! :)

I link it here, someone might find it helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-CnmGz5sbI

Here is my code, after the solution:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Írd be az első számot!");
        double x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        while(x <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A szám nem lehet kisebb, vagy egyenlő mint 0! Próbáld újra! :)");
            x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Írd be a második számot!");
        double y = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while(y <=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A szám nem lehet kisebb, vagy egyenlő mint 0! Próbáld újra! :)");
            y = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        double sum = x + y;
        double dif = x - y;
        double sub = x / y;
        sub = Math.Round(sub, 2);
        double multi = x * y;

        Console.WriteLine("A két szám összege: " + sum);
        Console.WriteLine("A két szám különbsége: " + dif);
        Console.WriteLine("A két szám osztása: " + sub);
        Console.WriteLine("A két szám szorzata: " + multi);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}